# How to Call Stored Procedures or Triggers in Laravel 5.2

Tags: model-view-controller, plsql, laravel-5

What is method to call stored procedures or triggers in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

**Create stored procedure**

```
DB::unprepared("create PROCEDURE `updateTotal` 
( IN `rate` int,IN `qty` int, IN `id` int) 
BEGIN 
set @total := (rate * qty);
set @id := id;
UPDATE products set total = @total where id = @id;
END");
```

**Call the procedure**

```
DB::statement("CALL updateTotal('50', '5', '47')");
```

**Result updated: *250* w.r.t id 47**

Answer (score 0):

You can easily call stored procedure in laravel in two ways

### using parameter
without using parameter

```
class CheckController extends Controller
{
    public function callProcedure()
    {
     // Calling Stored Procedure from MySQL
     $alluser = DB::select('call getalluser()'); 
     return $alluser;
    }
}
```

### Using parameter

```
class CheckController extends Controller
{
    public function callProcedure($id)
    {
     // Calling Stored Procedure from MySQL
     $specificuser = DB::select('call getspecificuser(?)',array($id));
     return $specificuser;
    }
}
```

You can refer the following article for better understanding [How to call stored procedure in laravel](https://www.studywithkishan.online/2020/09/call-stored-procedure-in-laravel-7.html)